# Why did I fail to update Password on FirebaseAuth even though I authenticated successfully?

Tags: android, kotlin

I fail to update Password on FirebaseAuth even though I authenticated successfully

```
val user = Firebase.auth.currentUser
        val credential = EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(user?.email!!, edtUpdateOldUpdatePass.text.toString().trim())
        user?.reauthenticate(credential)
            ?.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    user?.updatePassword(edtUpdatePass.getText().toString().trim())
                        ?.addOnCompleteListener{task ->
                            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                                Toast.makeText(this, "OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            else{
                                Toast.makeText(this, "NOT OK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
```

I tested it and it successfully authenticated the account, but it didn't change the password

Answer (score 0):

following this code

```
// Update Password
val updatePasswordBtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.updatePasswordBtn)
val edOriginalEmail = findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.edOriginalEmail)

val edOriginalPassword = findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.edOriginalPassword)
val edNewPassword = findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.edNewPassword)
updatePasswordBtn.setOnClickListener {
    val credentials = EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(
        edOriginalEmail.text.toString().trim(),
        edOriginalPassword.text.toString().trim()
    )
    val currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
    if (currentUser != null) {
        currentUser.reauthenticate(credentials).addOnSuccessListener {
            currentUser.updatePassword(
                edNewPassword.text.toString().trim()
            ).addOnSuccessListener {
                longToastShow("Password Updated Successfully")
            }.addOnFailureListener {
                it.message?.let { it1 -> longToastShow(it1) }
            }
        }.addOnFailureListener {
            it.message?.let { it1 -> longToastShow(it1) }
        }
    }

}

fun Context.longToastShow(msg:String){
    Toast.makeText(this,msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
}
```

if you no idea this playlist watch [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLlSuJy9SfzvFNtX4C8FPLzfMcokmF1kV_)

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't seem to work, the authentication is successful but the password change is not

Comment: Login is required after that this password change

Comment: Please, for a correct answer refer to this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer. Not only it's not working, but you didn't even try to explain your answer.